# How to show input date in YYYY-MM-DD format

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, date

I want to show input date in  YYYY-MM-DD format. I don't want to use moment.js like shown in the link [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format)

When I select date I want date to be shown as "YYYY-MM-DD" format. Here is what I tried

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<body >
  <input type="date" id="bday" required pattern="\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}">
  <input type="date" id="bday" date-format="YYYY-MM-DD">
</body>
```

I am running this using electron framework which has chromium built-in. I still wonder if there is a way to change format of date after selecting date.

Comment: Why would you want to overwrite the format the user has selected?

Comment: Suppose user has selected "17/02/2020".Inside the input field,  I want date to be shown as 2020-02-17

Comment: This is a requirement for UI design

Comment: Then tell them that the user/client knows best how a date has to be formatted. The server receives the date in YYYY-MM-DD format.

Comment: I recall `type="date"` cannot do what you want. It's dependent on the OS language and time-zone settings. Correct me if I'm mistaken. Use `type="text"` and use JS - or respect the user settings! - and fix the date on server-side.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any way to change input type="date" format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format)

Comment: Use Jquery datepicker.

Comment: Thanks to all I think best would be to use jquery datepicker